# Scanning files around 58 GB in coldfusion and finding a word count in that file

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfc

I have written code and through loop it actually scans words and find count of provided word. But this works only when data is somewhat less than 1 GB and request time out around 30 mins. Can anyone please suggest any better solution to scan and find count of word in a file so that I dont have to increase request time out more than 30 mins and it scans such huge amount of data. Is it possible through coldfusion or I should look for some other technology.

Comment: Are your text located in different files?

Comment: Look in to how to use SOLR along with ColdFusion. That is an indexing application, built in CF.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1824681

Comment: Or you could look at ElasticSearch which is optimised for this kind of task. The reason I have not put this in an official answer is that it is a Node.js technology, but extremely easy to implement on the server. And this is a brilliant & simple tutorial for beginners to understand: https://appdividend.com/amp/2018/06/29/node-js-elastic-search-tutorial-example/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fappdividend.com%2F2018%2F06%2F29%2Fnode-js-elastic-search-tutorial-example%2F&__twitter_impression=true

Comment: https://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/cfdocs/htmldocs/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ef2f-7ffd.html

Comment: What kind of file? Can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

## My Two Cents;

When it comes to processing large files in Coldfusion (or Lucee) I always consider using an alternative technology.

In order to process the file, you would need to load the file into memory ahead of processing. If you were working directly in Java you would use a buffer object and only keep the current line in memory at a time. If you delegate that work to Coldfusion, you don't guarantee that the lines are eligible for Garbage collection so its possible that you end up eating your memory and slowing things down. In addition to this, you need to store each unique word in some sort of structure against its word count, which means you'll have a few words used a lot of times, and many words used only once; another (potentially) large consumer of memory.

These things considered, my goto for larger files is either to start using Java directly to ensure that i'm using the correct buffering technique or creating a utility in an alternative tool such as python or ruby and delegating the work via cfexecute. *That said*, there's not reason you can't do this in CF you just need to look at what part of the process is slowing you down and dealing with that first and optimizing. Could you offload the job into a cfthread and pickup the results later? Would a better data structure or method of storage suit?

### tl;dr

It's impossible to be any more specific without seeing the data and the code.